# Can multiple silo add bonus to same harvester?

Tags: command-conquer-tiberium-alliances

If I have multiple silos next to one harvester do they then all add bonus to the harvester or is the bonus only applied once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding multiple Silos next to a Harvester will increase the Bonus to the harvester for each Silo.

[image]